# Style LitElement component form outside

Tags: javascript, css, lit-element, emotion

Is it possible to overwrite default styles of lit Element component for example like in the [mui](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)? Or just pass css property created with Emotion.js

Comment: you can try document.querySelector('#id').shadowRoot.querySelector('#id2').style.property = "new style"

Comment: I found a better way. Just create an attribute property and put it into a render method in a style tag after default styles.

Answer (score 0):

No, as LitElements have internal adopted CSS and shadow roots. They inherit styles like regular elements, but any internal CSS they have will cascade higher.

However, many use CSS variables to add styling options, and you can use these yourself in your components. See more here: https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#theming